# Is there any CherryPy's equivalent to Django's Message framework (MessageMiddleware)?

Tags: python, django, cherrypy

Is there any tool in CherryPy that provides equivalent/similar functionality as Django's Message Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though CherryPy doesn't seem to have an out-of-box message option, this seems like a good snippet for it: [Message Flash with view and HTML in CherryPy](http://www.mail-archive.com/turbogears@googlegroups.com/msg27568.html)